# Load Balancing of 2 instances in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, https, virtual-machine, load-balancing, nginx-ingress

I have two VM's (in AWS cloud) connected to single DB. Each VM is having same application running. I want to load balance those two VM's and route based on the traffic. (Like if traffic is more on one VM instance then it should switch to another VM).
Currently I am accessing 2 different instances with 2 different IP addresses with HTTP. Now I want to access those 2 VM's with HTTPS and route the instances with same DNS like (https://dns name/service1/),
(https://dns name/service2/)

[image: Image view of problem statement]

How can I do load balancing using nginx ingress.

I am new to AWS cloud. Can someone help me or guide me or suggest me some appropriate related references in getting the solution to it.

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing

Comment: You should set up an Application Load Balancer on AWS, and take a look at the link posted by @jordanm in previous comment

Comment: Sure thankyou. .

Answer (score 0):

AWS offers an **Elastic Load Balancing** service.

From [What is Elastic Load Balancing? - Elastic Load Balancing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/userguide/what-is-load-balancing.html):

> **Elastic Load Balancing** automatically distributes your incoming traffic across multiple targets, such as EC2 instances, containers, and IP addresses, in one or more Availability Zones. It monitors the health of its registered targets, and routes traffic only to the healthy targets. Elastic Load Balancing scales your load balancer as your incoming traffic changes over time. It can automatically scale to the vast majority of workloads.

You can use this ELB service *instead of* running another Amazon EC2 instance with nginx. ([Charges](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/pricing/) apply.)

Alternatively, you could configure your domain name on **Amazon Route 53** to use [Weighted routing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/routing-policy.html#routing-policy-weighted):

> Weighted routing lets you associate multiple resources with a single domain name (example.com) or subdomain name (acme.example.com) and choose how much traffic is routed to each resource. This can be useful for a variety of purposes, including load balancing and testing new versions of software.

This would distribute the traffic when resolving the DNS Name rather than using a Load Balancer. It's not quite the same because DNS information is cached, so the same client would continue to be redirected to the same server until the cache is cleared. However, it is practically free to use.